# Loading an xml file and displaying in listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an xml file containing some student information. The grades of the students should be loaded to one list box. If i select a grade from that listbox the student names of that grade should be displayed in another listbox.
This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<dropdown>
    <grade id = "1" title = "1">
        <description>Grade 1</description>
    <st id = "1">Sachintha</st>
    <st id = "1">Darshana</st>
        <st monitor="true" id = "1">Patric</st>
    </grade>

   <grade id = "2" title = "2">
        <description>Grade 2</description>
    <st id = "2">Jane</st>
    <st id = "2">Rita</st>
    <st monitor="true" id = "2">Michael</st>
    </grade>

    <grade id = "3" title = "3">
        <description>Grade 3</description>
    <st id = "3">Brad</st>
    <st id = "3">Angelina</st>
    <st monitor="true" id = "3">Ariana</st>
    </grade>
</dropdown>
```

this is what i have done so far .. The second dropdown (monitor) is not filling according to the selected item of the first dropdown (grade).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "XmlGrade.xml",
                dataType: "xml",    
                success: function(xml) {
                    var select = $('#grade');
                    var select2 = $('#monitor');


                    $(xml).find('dropdown').each(function(){

                        $(this).find('grade').each(function(){


                            var title = $(this).attr('title');


                            var description =  $(this).find('description').text();


                            select.append("<option  value='"+ title +"'>"+description+"</option>");



                        });
                    });

                    $('#grade').change(function() {


                        select2.empty();

                        var selectedVal = $('#grade option:selected').attr('value');



                        $(xml).find('[title="'+selectedVal+'"]').each(function(){

                            $(this).children('[id]').each(function(){

                                select2.append('<option>'+ $(this).text() +'</option>');

                            })


                        })



                    });





                } 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <select id="grade">   
        </select>
        <select id="monitor">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've recreated your code and the drop-down fills with the code you've provided.  The only change I had to make was the path to the XML file, which in my case was in the same directory in an MVC project, so the URL provided to the jQuery ajax function became, url: "./XmlGrade.xml".  Have you tried opening the html page in Google Chrome, then pressing F12 to bring up Developer Tools?  Then click the Sources tab, expand the directory structure until you see the html file.  Double-click, place a breakpoint in the ajax success callback to see if you're getting there.  Also view Network tab for XML

Comment: You'll need to bring up your html page in the browser (Chrome preferably), press F12 to bring up Developer Tools, then press F5 to reload the page in order to capture the Network traffic on the Network tab.  There you can see the response code for each request.  You can also click on each network request and click either the Preview or Response tab to view the XML.  One other note, you might want to update your jQuery version with this script URL: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: The one thing that is not working as perhaps desired with your current code, is that when the page loads, the 2nd dropdown does not populate with values until you change the values in the 1st dropdown.

Comment: I ran this html in the browser using an http server. I downloaded it from this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: Thank in advance. I found the problem . I have to use the "Id" instead of  "title" when setting the selectedVal to the find method when appending the second dropdown.